# React NavLink's open to blank page, need reload to load content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am running into a problem when trying to load into new pages on my website. When links are clicked, the web address will change to the new address, but the page will only be blank until manually reloaded. I am using react.js and React Routers v6.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
)
```

App.js:

```
import './App.scss'
import {  Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Layout from './components/Layout'
import Home from './components/Home'
import About from './components/About'
import Contact from './components/Contact'
import Portfolio from './components/Portfolio'
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Sidebar />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={< Layout />}>
        <Route exact index element={ < Home />}/>
        <Route exact path="about" element={< About />}/>
        <Route exact path="/contact" element={< Contact />}/>
        <Route exact path="/portfolio" element={< Portfolio />}/>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
  }

export default App
```

Sidebar:

```
import './index.scss'
import {  NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import {faHome, faUser, faEnvelope, faSuitcase} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faLinkedin, faBehanceSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'



const Sidebar = () => (

    <div className = 'nav-bar'>
        
        <nav>
            <NavLink end activeclassname = "active" to="/">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} color="#4d4d4e" />
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink exact="true" activeclassname="active" className = "about-link" to="about">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} color="#4d4d4e" />
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink exact="true" activeclassname="active" className = "portfolio-link" to="portfolio">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSuitcase} color="#4d4d4e" />
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink exact="true" activeclassname="active" className = "contact-link" to="contact">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} color="#4d4d4e" />
            </NavLink>
        </nav>
        <ul> 
            <li>
                <a target="-blank" rel='noreferrer' href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/braden-mcgee/">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLinkedin} color="#4d4d4e"/>
                </a>
                <a target="-blank" rel='noreferrer' href="https://www.behance.net/bradenrmcgee">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBehanceSquare} color="#4d4d4e"/>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
)

export default Sidebar
```

I have tried to manually load the page with an onClick function in the NavLink tags, but then I have to click the navigation twice before being loaded into the correct page. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the routes or links. Are there any errors? Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox[(https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I ended up looking in the wrong place. The routes were okay and working properly, however I was using the useEffect hook to animate titles on my pages incorrectly.

Originally, I had:

```
useEffect(() => {
    return setTimeout(() => {
    setLetterClass('text-animate-hover')
    }, 3000);
}, []);
```

which created blank pages when I clicked on the navigation. This happened because I was returning something that wasn't a function, making the useEffect hook fail. So, once I deleted the return from useEffect, turning it into this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    setLetterClass('text-animate-hover')
    }, 3000);
}, []);
```

the navigation and website started working.
So, this problem was within my actual pages, not within my index, App, or Sidebar files.

Comment: Ah, I see now.... Yeah, this is about the 3rd or 4th time I've seen this exact code and issue come up on SO. Always the issue with the `useEffect` hook and `setTimeout`. Is it all part of some class/course?

Answer (score -1):

In Your App.js change the route. Hope it will work.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Sidebar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<PortFolio />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
  }

export default App
```